# How to set up dev environment with AWS Mobile hub?

Tags: amazon-web-services, serverless, aws-amplify, aws-mobilehub

Currently using AWS Mobile Hub for my React native app and React web app. It was very convenience for us to build an app in a short time but now we are getting into the point that we need a proper dev environment that we can run separately from production Mobile Hub.

What is the best way to set up a dev environment with AWS Mobile Hub? Also, how to integrate it with Github?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mobile Hub does not support dev environment now. The best way is to create another project used as dev.

For GitHub integration, you can follow this link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/deploy-to-aws-mobile-hub-from-your-github-repository/.